# Is the set of TMs whose language reduces to a fixed CFL also CFL?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

L = {  < M > | M is a TM and L(M) <= { $0^n 1^{2n}$} }

Here <= means polynomially reducible to

Is L CFL?

---

If L(M) can be polynomially reduced to a CFL then L(M) should also be CFL as if "A" is reducible to "B" then we can solve "A" if we know how to solve "B" ? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The last statement seems wrong. Note that any PTIME language $L$ can be reduced (in polynomial time) to the CFL $\{a\}$. This includes many non-CFL languages $L$.

Comment: @chi, can you please give an example ? I am new to this topic(decidability).

Comment: Hint: If $L(M) \in P$ then $\langle M \rangle \in L$.

Comment: So can we write L as L={ <M> | L(M) is CFL} which is undecidable and Non R.E by rice theorem?

Comment: Take $L$ to be any non-CFL, PTIME language. E.g. the set of the words $a^nb^nc^n$ with any $n\geq 0$ is known to be non-CFL and it is surely PTIME. Then you can trivially reduce it to $\{a\}$ as follows: given a word $w$, in polynomial time we check if it is of the form $a^nb^nc^n$. If it is, output $a$, otherwise, output $aa$ (or any other word $\neq a$). So, a non-CFL can reduce in polynomial time to a CFL.

Comment: Thanks @chi, is my above comment regarding finding class of language using rice theorem correct?

Comment: You can't rewrite $L$ in that way -- that's not an equivalent property. You have to use the original definition.

Comment: So how do I prove it's undecidable?  Here in this question we have to check whether L(M) is polynomially reducible to CFL is decidable or not, right ? Why is it not equivalent to checking if L(M) is CFL ?